# Google map not rendering second time

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using controller to show google map in my application. When I load the page first time the map is rendering properly. But when I try second time the map is not loading. It is showing grey area. I tried different solutions like triggering resize event. But no luck.

This is my initializeMap() in controller

```
                $scope.initializeMap = function() {

                    var mapOptions = {
                        zoom : 4,
                        center : new google.maps.LatLng($scope.latitude,
                                $scope.longitude),

                        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    }

                    var mapsss = document.getElementById('map');

                    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(mapsss, mapOptions);

                    $scope.markers = [];

                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                    var createMarker = function(info) {

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map : $scope.map,
                            position : new google.maps.LatLng(
                                    info.latitude, info.longitude),
                            title : info.name,
                            icon : info.icon
                        });
                        marker.content = '';

                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',
                                function() {
                                    infoWindow.setContent('<h2>'
                                            + marker.title + '</h2>');
                                    infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
                                });

                        $scope.markers.push(marker);

                    }

                    for (i = 0; i < $scope.locations.length; i++) {

                        createMarker($scope.locations[i]);
                    }

                    $scope.openInfoWindow = function(e, selectedMarker) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
                    }

                    google.maps.event.trigger($scope.map, 'resize');
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.310774,
                            66.225586);
                    $scope.map.setCenter(myLatlng);

                }

            });
```

I am not sure what is the problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have found the solution myself :) It seems like an issue or behavior or whatsoever with maps api which doesn't render the map properly in case the div is hidden. So I removed the ng-show which I had in the div and it worked!! The map rendered properly.